# Cannot load and execute third party .js in .phtml

Tags: magento2.3.2

I use Magento 2.3.2
Added into header.phtml

```
<div class="zalo-share-button" data-href="https://magento.com/" data-oaid="579745863508352884" data-layout="2" data-color="blue" data-customize=false></div>
```

And

```
<script src="https://sp.zalo.me/plugins/sdk.js"></script>
```

=> Not load js from sdk.js, and cannot create iframe.

It working in html
https://codepen.io/huuquyasb/pen/yLBvGbr 
http://prntscr.com/p3oi2a

Hopefully somebody can help.
Thanks for reading this.

Comment: check console log

Comment: I checked. It has nothing error or warning

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

> Create `default.xml` in
>   `Vendor/Moduleview/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="https://sp.zalo.me/plugins/sdk.js" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

---

> **Cretae `iframe` in html**

```
<iframe src="https://sp.zalo.me/plugins/sdk.js" height="300" width="400">  </iframe>
```

Comment: It not working. other solution ?

Comment: check updated answer